# scalar product vs projection

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The scalar  is defined as the length of the projection of A onto B.

Now suppose $A=(1,1)$ and $B=(2,1)$. The scalar would be 3, while the projection of A onto B would be the vector $(\frac{6}{5}, \frac{3}{5})$, which has a length of $3\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}} \ne 3$. How is it possible?

(Please excuse my stupid question)

Answer (score 0):

Define $J(a,b):=(-b,a)$ the counterclockwise rotation of $(a,b)$ by $\pi/2$.  Then $\langle(a,b),(c,d)\rangle=\det\bigl((a,b),J(c,d)\bigr)\rangle$, which is the (orientated) area of the parallelogram spanned by $(a,b)$ and $J(c,d)$.  Hence your interpretation of the scalar product is wrong (unless one of the vectors is a unit vector and both vectors are positive orientated).

Comment: I found it here http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/dotprod/dotprod.html 
"The scalar projection of b onto a is the length of the segment AB shown in the figure below."

Comment: As I stated: *unless one vector is a unit vector*.